# Display HTML Table from JSON view using Knockout MVC 4 and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I simply want to display data on my webpage and allow users to click a button and return some updated data.

I have a model that looks like:

```
public class ReportModel
{
    public string ReportDate { get; set; }
    public List<Common.Rep> ReportList { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the Rep class:

```
public class Rep
{
    public string ReportName { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfRows { get; set; }
    public string HasData { get; set; }
    public bool checkBox { get; set; }
    public string ResultMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have a controller that does this:

This method returns the data to the page on page load:

```
public JsonResult Index()
{
    var model = new ReportModel();
    model.ReportDate = "1/31/2014";
    model.ReportList = new List<Models.Common.Rep>();
    model.ReportList.Add(
          new Models.Common.Rep()
          {
              ReportName ="test report",
              NumberOfRows = 50, 
              HasData = "Yes",
              checkBox = false,
              ResultMessage = "Message"
          });
    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Now I have my view:

```
<table>
    <tr style="font-weight:bold">
        <td>
            Report Name
        </td>
        <td>
            Number Of Rows
        </td>
        <td>
            Has Data
        </td>
        <td>
            Result Message
        </td>
        <td>
            Check
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Report">
        <tr>
            <td> <span data-bind="text: ReportName"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: NumberOfRows"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: HasData"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: ResultMessage"></span></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checkBox"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And on the same page I have my scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    //SET INITIAL VALUES ON PAGE WITH KNOCKOUT
    var initialModel = new KOViewModel(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));
    model.Date(initialModel.Date);
    model.Report(initialModel.Report);

//SET THE KNOCKOUT OBSERVABLES
var viewmodel =
   {
      Date: ko.observable(initialModel.Date)
      Report: ko.observableArray(initialModel.Report)
  };

//APPLY KNOCKOUT BINDINGS
$(document).ready(function() { 
    ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);
});
```

When I run the page I don't see a table but just the JSON itself at the top of the page. This is what T see on the page:
    {"ReportDate":"1/31/2014","ReportList":[{"ReportName":"test         report","NumberOfRows":50,"HasData":"Yes","checkBox":false,"ResultMessage":"Message"}]}

How do I get the JSON into a table and link the Observable fields?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm not familiar with KOViewModel so I cannot comment on that. What does seem odd is that you have an action returning JSON but you don't call it from your script. Are you perhaps navigating to the action directly in the browser? If so, that will of course show you JSON.

Instead, change the Index action to return ActionResult and make sure the HTML and scripts are included in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need to begin with to get your example working, all be it with mimicked json:

```
var json = {"ReportDate":"1/31/2014","ReportList":[{"ReportName":"test report","NumberOfRows":50,"HasData":"Yes","checkBox":false,"ResultMessage":"Message"}]};


// create a javascript representation of the c# object, with observables
var ViewModel = function(reportDate, reportList) {
    self = this;
    self.ReportDate = ko.observable(reportDate);
    self.Report = ko.observable(reportList);
}


// Apply the bindings to your new object
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(json.ReportDate, json.ReportList));
```

See here for the working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Tzce4/2/

Everything else is correct, as all I needed to create this was a straight copy and paste of your json.